# fetching the data from database using angularjs and JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

Hi iam trying to fetch the data from database using angularjs but it is not displaying any data.I just started to learn AngularJs.Can any one help me this.Here is my code

income.html

```
<div class="container jumbotron"  ng-init= "getIncomeSource()" ng-controller="IncomeSourcesController" id="homejumbotron">
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name of the Employer</th>
        <th>Income From Salary</th>
        <th>TDS Deducted</th>
        <th></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in incomesources" >

    <td>{{x.company_name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.user_income}}</td>
    <td>{{x.tax_deducted_salary}}</td>


    </tbody>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('accountantApp', []);
app.controller('IncomeSourcesController', function($scope,$http) {
console.log("inside homecontroller:::");    
$scope.getIncomeSource = function(){
$scope.user = "";
console.log("Inside getPersonalInfo::::::");    
$http({
        method  : 'POST',
         url        : '../model/incomesources.php',           
        headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  },
              data      : {"action": "GetIncomeSources"}
       })
       .success(function( data,status, headers) {
        console.log("Response data:"+ JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.success != undefined && data.success != '')
        {
          $scope.user = data;
        }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers) {
        alert("Error occured while retrieving:"+status);
        console.log("Error data::::"+ data);
        console.log("status::::"+ status);
        });             
};  
});
```

incomesources.php

```
function getIncomeSources()
{
session_start();
 $userInfo = $_SESSION['USER'];
 $userEmailid= $userInfo-> getEmailid();
 $res="SELECT *  FROM user_salary_details  WHERE email ='$userEmailid'";
 $result=mysql_query($res);            
 if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
     $companyname  = $row["company_name"];
     $userincome = $row["user_income"];
     $employetype   = $row["employe_type"];
     $tan     = $row["tan_employer"];
     $tax = $row["tax_deducted_salary"];
     $address = $row["address"];
     $state = $row["state"];
     $city=$row["city"];
     $pin=$row["pincode"];
     $data = array(
                    "success"   =>  "success",
                "companyname"   =>  $companyname,
                    "userincome"    =>  $userincome,
                "employetype"   =>  $employetype,
                "tan"   =>  $tan,
                    "tax"   =>  $tax,
                    "address"    =>      $address,
                    "state"   =>      $state,
                     "city" =>$city,
                     "pin"=>$pin,
              );

     echo json_encode($data);         
     }else{
        echo "No record exists for this user::";            
     }   
}
```

Comment: Here u need to add one more parameter data in success fn

Comment: which parameter i need to add

Comment: .success(function( status, headers, data) {
        console.log("Response data:"+ JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: console.log("Response data:"+ JSON.stringify(data) Here you used data but data is not defined anywhere

Comment: console what it shows?

Comment: Response data is getting null

Comment: In response the data is printing but in the view it is not displaying the data

Comment: Can you share what your getting in console

Comment: this seems working for me [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/m0esliz7JLYInogiz0V2?p=preview)

Comment: Response data:{"success":"success","companyname":"company","userincome":"10000","employetype":null,"tan":"A123Thj","tax":"100","address":"address","state":"AP","city":"city","pin":"123456"}

Comment: As i changed the code so it is printing the response data can you check that but it should show in view

Comment: Can one help me this

Answer (score 0):

Is your incomesources.php was working initially?

The WHERE clause in the select statement is looking for email='$userEmailid'

i think you want the content of $userEmailid. So try change to

```
$res="SELECT *  FROM user_salary_details  WHERE email ='". $userEmailid ."'";
```

**EDIT**
Since your php file is working, and you mentioned in above comments that you are able to see the return value in console, lets see your html and js code.

In your html please change to

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in user" >

    <td>{{x.companyname}}</td>
    <td>{{x.userincome}}</td>
    <td>{{x.tax}}</td>
```

The properties in {{x.something}} is based on the php return properties, not from database column name.

In your js file, try initialize the $scope.user outside $scope.getIncomeSource function and init it as an array. For example

```
console.log("inside homecontroller:::");   

$scope.user = []; // this

$scope.getIncomeSource = function(){

console.log("Inside getPersonalInfo::::::");    
$http({
```

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry, I thought the return from the php is an array. It just a json object. Can you please change the line to $scope.user = {};